# Проблема при post запросе retrofit android

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, retrofit2

У меня есть приложение для логина, в котором я использую библиотеку retrofit и вот у меня при работе приложения получились такие логи:

```
    W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://0/v1/login
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 43
D/OkHttp: {"login":"","password":""}
    --> END POST (43-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error https://0/v1/login (227ms)
    Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 09:11:22 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    Content-Length: 531
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error or
    misconfiguration and was unable to complete
    your request.</p>
    <p>Please contact the server administrator at 
     [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred,
     and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
    <p>More information about this error may be available
    in the server error log.</p>
    </body></html>
    <-- END HTTP (531-byte body)
```

и вот я не могу понять, вот вроде уже все работает, мне тут помогли добрые люди на stackoverflow, за что им кстати огромное спасибо, но вот не могу понять что еще этому приложению от меня нужно, все должно работать я так думаю. Может кто знает в чем может быть проблема, потому-что у меня уже кончились идеи и я уже все что мог все перепробовал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что такой домен\энпоинт не найден, проверьте что адрес энпоинта указан верно и должен принимать POST запрос

Comment: обновил ошибку, так как исправил одну вылезла другая))

Comment: А это уже на сервере надо смотреть, что там неправильно, неизвестно что ему не понравилось

Comment: та я уже связался с бекэндом то у них проблемка одна была все-таки но пока-что я не смог связаться с сервером из приложения, все равно спасибо за помощь))

Comment: С помощью Postman протестируй свой api